# Structure of web page. Huge gap. HTML or CSS issue?

Tags: html, css

[image]Hi there,

I am trying to build a web page and i have the following problem. I tried to upload a photo but I cannot because I don't have enough votes. I have a contacts page and my problem is that there is a huge gap between the contacts (little photos with people) and the grey layer in the bottom (please vote for me so that I can upload a photo to show you what I mean). I am really confused and I don't know where the problem might be. Here I give some information:

I have created two lists (divs) with photos and contacts (in this picture you can see 2 photos of the leftlist (as i called it) div and one photo of the rightlist div.

The CSS for these two are the following:

```
#leftlist {
width:430px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 720px;}

#rightlist {
width:430px;
position: relative;
left: 450px;
bottom: 720px;
top: -670px;}
```

These two divs I placed them inside the white box as you can see from the photo which I named container. The CSS for container is:

```
.container {
width:950px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;}
```

Here I add the whole code of the container including whats inside:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="box">
            <div class="border-top">
               <div class="border-right">
                  <div class="border-bot">
                     <div class="border-left">
                        <div class="left-top-corner">
                           <div class="right-top-corner">
                              <div class="right-bot-corner">
                                 <div class="left-bot-corner">
                                   <div class="inner">
                                       <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                                    <h2 align="center">Sales and Customer Service Team</h2>
                                      <h2 align="center"><br />
                                        <br />
                                      </h2>

                                    <div id="leftlist">
                                    <ul class="list2">
                                          <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/blabla.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>blabla </strong>
                                             President<br />
                                             <br />
                                             <span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:blabla@blabla.it">blabla@sblabla.it</a></span><br />
                                      <span class="style100">Tel: +39 02 00000001</span><br />
                                      </h4></li>
                                          <li></li>
                                          <br />


                                          <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/blabla.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>blabla </strong>
                                             General Sales Manager<br />
                                             <br />
<span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:blabla@blabla.it">blabla@blabla.it</a></span><br />
                                               <span class="style100">Tel: +39 02 00000023</span><br />
                                      </h4>
                                      </li>
                                      <li></li>
                                          <br />


                                          <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/blabla.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>blabla </strong>
                                   Sales Manager<br />
                                  <br />
                                  <span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:blabla@sblabla.it">blabla@sblabla.it</a></span><br />
                                  Tel: +39 02 00000021<br />
                                      </h4></li>
                                          <li></li>
                                          <br />


                                          <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/lara.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>Lara blabla</strong>
                                             Sales and Logistics<br />
                                             <br />
                                             <span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:larablabla@blabla.it">lara.blabla@blabla.it</a></span><br />
                                             Tel: +39 02 00000022<br />
                                      </h4></li>
                                          <li></li>
                                          <br />
                                </ul>
                                   </div>
                                      <div id="rightlist">
                                      <ul class="list2">    
                                      <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/blabla.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>blabla</strong>
                                             Laboratory Manager and Quality Control<br />
                                             <br />
                                             <span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:blabla@blabla.it">blabla@blabla</a></span><br />
                                             Tel: +39 02 00000020<br />
                                      </h4></li>
                                          <li></li>
                                          <br />


                                    <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/blabla.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>blabla</strong>Technical Department<br />
                                               <br />
                                               <span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:blabla@blabla.it">blabla@blabla.it</a></span><br />
                                               Tel: +39 02 00000012<br />
                                      </h4></li>
                                          <li></li>
                                          <br />

                                    <li>
                                             <img alt="" src="images/blabla.jpg" />
                                             <h4><strong>blabla</strong>Safety Manager<br />
                                               <br />
                                               <span class="style100">Email: <a href="mailto:blabla@blabla.it">blabla@blabla.it</a></span><br />
                                               Tel: +39 02 00000011<br />
                                      </h4></li>
                                    <li></li>
                                      </ul>
                                     </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <div align="center"></div>

                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
    </div>
         <!-- box end -->
  </div>
```

Tip: there are more photos and contact details that are not visible in the photo I upload as i wanted to show you the gap between the container div and the next div (grey layer).

I am really sorry in advance if I am asking something stupid but I've been working on this for 8 hours now and I can't seem to find a solution. Maybe the solution is really stupid but my brain feels like its frying right now :p

Comment: Please show a live link or a screen shot

Comment: I don't really understand how to do that. I cannot upvote my questions. 
As for a link to the photo here it is http://yfrog.com/2cscreenshot20100902at151p

Comment: I am really sorry guys, I just realised how to accept answers!

Comment: Is there a special reason why you have 14 DIVs?

Comment: In which operating system and with which browser(s) have you tested your site?

Comment: I am using so many divs for the rounded corners. I am working on Dreamweaver CS5 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there are a couple of issues with the code you have here, most notably the number of divs you are using (I assume that's just for the rounded corners?). However I believe your issue is caused by the positioning of the #leftlist and #rightlist. I can't see a reason for these to be position:relative (also when used you should only set the top value or the bottom value, not both (e.g. 'top:0px' OR 'bottom:0px').)

What is happening is you are moving the #rightlist from it's default position under the #leftlist. Because you are using position:relative and not position:absolute the original position is retained. The extra whitespace you are seeing is where the #rightlist should, by default, appear.

I would not use position in this instance. A better alternative is to use 'float:left' on both lists. If you do this your css will end up being the same for each list - try this:

```
#leftlist
#rightlist {
    width:430px;
    float:left;
    }
```

This may collapse the #container div which can be fixed in a number of ways, the simplest being adding 'overflow:hidden;height:100%' to #container. A quick google search should provide many more options if required.

Another alternative would be to use 'display:inline-block' instead of 'float:left' although this can cause issues in older browsers - it really depends on what browsers you need to support.

Hope this helps put you on the right track. Please leave a comment if I'm not being clear and I'll edit my response!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The 'display:inline-block' worked for me. Latest version of Safari, Chrome and Firefox are desired support pages so it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following in order to attempt to identify where the problem lies:

Install the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) add-on in Firefox, load up your page then use the 'Outline Block Level Elements' option to get a visual display of all the elements that make up your page.

Comment: Also, the [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) add-on is helpful if you don't have it installed already.

Comment: I am mostly working with Safari. Do you have any safari add-on similar to this one? It looks really nice as I tested it on Firefox.

Comment: Safari has its own web inspector tools which are very similar to firebug (although not as good imo). You have to enable them in the preferences though. Here's more:  http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#developer

Comment: Wow I had no idea Safari had such a cool extension!!! Thank you very much!!! Really helpful tip!